# Prove that $f$ is one-to-one on $U$

Tags: calculus, functions

$U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ which is also convex. $f:U\to \mathbb R^n$ is of the class $C^1$.  If the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ satisfies the condition:  $\forall x \in U\quad ||Dg(x)||\lt 1$

Prove that $f$ is one-to-one on $U$.

It seems like a part of the proof of inverse function theorem. But, there may be better solutions... From the mean value theorem we have:
$\forall x,y\in U\quad ||g(x)-g(y)||\le||x-y||$
$\implies ||f(x)-x-f(y)+y||\le||x-y||$
$\implies ||x-y||-||f(x)-f(y)||\le ||x-y||$
$\implies ||f(x)-f(y)|| \ge0$
But this doesn't help me...

Comment: Probably the right condition is $\|Dg(x)\| < 1$, otherwise any constant function $f$ provides a counter-example.

Comment: @Rigel Thanks... i corrected my mistake... Do you have any suggestions for the proof?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is almost correct.

Assume by contradiction that there exist $x,y\in U$, with $x\neq y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$.
Then you get
$$
\|y-x\| = \|f(x)-x - f(y) + y\| = \|g(x) - g(y)\| < \|x-y\|,
$$
a contradiction.

The last inequality follows from the fact that $U$ is convex and $\|Dg(x)\| < 1$ for every $x\in U$. Namely, if $x,y\in U$ and $x\neq y$:
$$
\|g(x) - g(y)\| = \left\|\int_0^1 Dg((1-t)x + ty) \cdot (y-x)\, dt\right\|
$$
$$
\leq \|x-y\| \int_0^1 \|Dg((1-t)x + ty)\|\, dt < \|x-y\|.
$$